# SciDraw: Adding Canvas coordinates to plot coordinates

Tags: scidraw

The following code

```
<< SciDraw`;
Figure[
 FigurePanel[
  {FigLine[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]];
   p1 = {30, 80};
   p2 = DisplacePoint[p1, Canvas[{20, 20}]];
   FigInset[Show[Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}, 1]]], Transpose@{p1, p2}];
   }],
 CanvasSize -> {4, 3}
 ]
```

fails with

> ```
> Transpose::nmtx: The first two levels of {{30,80},Object[Object$1058]}
> cannot be transposed.
> ```

Why is that? The documentation claims that

> The DisplacePoint function generates a new point by moving a given
>   vector displacement “relative to” a given point. (You can actually add
>   several displacements d1 , d2 , . . .at once.) A displacement may be
>   given as {dx,dy}, Scaled[{dx,dy}], or Canvas[{dx,dy}]

What is the type returned by this `DisplacementPoint`? How can I convert it back to regular coordinates?

Comment: I didn't know the answer, but after browsing the documentation I found `AnchorCoordinates`. Isn't this what you need to apply to `p2`?  No answer because I don't have the time to get to the bottom of it, but if you figure it out, please do self-answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, as Szabolcs points out in the comments, `AnchorCoordinates` is used to convert any SciDraw points to coordinates, not just anchors. This is how it works:

```
Figure[
  FigurePanel[{
    FigLine[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]];
    p1 = {0.8, 0.6};
    p2 = DisplacePoint[p1, Canvas[{20, 20}]];
    FigInset[Show[Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}, 1]]], 
      Transpose@{p1, AnchorCoordinates[p2]}];
   }],
 CanvasSize -> {4, 3}]
```

[image]

and with 40 instead of 20 pixels in `Canvas[...]`

[image]

One application for this approach is to create regions that are square on the canvas but located at given plot coordinates.